# Printing html file on server without browser

Tags: java

I have a html template file, i am using server side java code to fill in the template and now want to print the file on the same server. Now when i print it, html tags are also coming. What should i do to get html formatting also rather than tags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A browser is an HTML rendering engine. If you want the HTML to be rendered ("formatted") you need a browser or some alternate rendering engine.

If you want to print from the command line, you can use a command line printing tool such as [Command Line Print](http://sites.google.com/site/torisugari/commandlineprint2), which will send your document through Firefox like this:

```
firefox -print http://www.example.com/index.html
```

or

```
firefox -print file://path/to/your/file.html
```

Comment: If only that extension worked on Firefox>3... :(  Any good alternatives?